# Count non-empty cells in pandas dataframe rows and add counts as a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

Using Python, **I want to count the number of cells in a row that has data** in it, in a pandas data frame **and record the count in the leftmost cell of the row**.

[image: Frame showing count column on left as requested]

Comment: Please post an example of your data and the desired output, as well as the code you've tried so far.

Comment: I added a link to an image in the description. I apologize for not providing detailed information. This is my first time posting on stack overflow.

Comment: As alluded to in @KeithDowd's answer, "empty" cells aren't really "empty", they might contain empty strings, some numpy nan value, None, etc. So if you want to count those empty cells, it's important to check what is actually in them.

Comment: Any chance you might mark my response as the answer to your question? :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To count the number of cells missing data in each row, you probably want to do something like this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.isnull().sum(), axis='columns')
```

Replace `df` with the label of your data frame.

You can create a new column and write the count to it using something like:

```
df['MISSING'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.isnull().sum(), axis='columns')
```

The column will be created at the end (rightmost) of your data frame.

You can move your columns around like this:

```
df = df[['Count', 'M', 'A', 'B', 'C']]
```

#### Update

I'm wondering if your missing cells are actually empty strings as opposed to `NaN` values. Can you confirm? I copied your screenshot into an Excel workbook. My full code is below:

```
df = pd.read_excel('count.xlsx', na_values=['', ' '])
df.head() # You should see NaN for empty cells
df['M']=df.apply(lambda x: x.isnull().sum(), axis='columns')
df.head() # Column M should report the values: first row: 0, second row: 1, third row: 2
df = df[['Count', 'M', 'A', 'B', 'C']]
df.head() # Column order should be Count, M, A, B, C
```

Notice the `na_values` parameter in the `pd.read_excel` method.

Comment: I am wondering where would the column be added. I need it added right after the leftmost column. So basically column B and shift all the data to the right.

Comment: I tested it out as well all the missing values just comes up as 4 instead of the actual count.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for helping, but I tried your final solution and that only gave me 0 for all the values in the missing column

Comment: I posted one more update. See if this helps you. i'm sorry this is so tricky.

Comment: my missing data are empty strings they are not nan values

Comment: You can specify that empty strings be read in as `NaN` values using the `na_values` parameter of the `pd.read_excel` method (see my updated answer with full code post). You can add new criteria to the list assigned to the `na_values` parameter to capture empty strings (or other values) that should be converted to `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked is there any way to do it without changing it to NaN anyway. If not I can al\ways change the NaN to empty spaces later or can I?

Comment: If possible would you be able to tell me how to get a count for the filled value as well

Comment: i think that can be done witgh just the count function i really appreciate your help thanks a lot

Comment: You can transform `NaN` values to strings, but I don't think you really need to. When you export your dataframe as a csv (using `df.to_csv`) or as an Excel worksheet (using `df.to_excel`) the `NaN` values will be removed and what is left will be null values. In other words, your exported data will not include `NaN` values. If you want to explicitly convert all `NaN` values to strings, use this: `df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True, inplace=True)`

Comment: Sure. Replace `isnull()` with `notnull()` and the counts will report the number of values that are not `NaN`.